# the if condition in javascript doesn't work,what's the solution

Tags: javascript

Within the function all conditions are fulfilled except the first IF

I have previously tried to put each bet in a separate bracket and did not respond, even using the switch bet and none of the bets in the switch.

```js
function my_information() {
  var information_statuss = ["the name dosnt import,please try again", "the family dosnt import,please try again", "the age dosnt import,please try again"];
  var status;
  var name = prompt("please import your name");
  var family = prompt("please import your family");
  var age = prompt("please import your age");
  (function() {
    if (name == null && family == null && age == null) {
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < information_statuss.length; i++) {
        alert(information_statuss[i]);
      }
    } else if (name == null || name == "") {
      status = information_statuss[0];
      alert(information_statuss[0]);
    } else if (family == null || family == "") {
      status = information_statuss[1];
      alert(information_statuss[1]);
    } else if (age == null || age == "") {
      status = information_statuss[2];
      alert(information_statuss[2]);
    } else {
      status = null;
      var person = new object_constructor(name, family, age);
      console.log(person);
      var people = [];
      people.push(person);
      var inf = document.getElementById('information');
      var info;
      for (I in people) {
        info +=
          "NAME : " + people[I].name + "<br>" +
          "FAMILY : " + people[I].family + "<br>" +
          "AGE : " + people[I].age + "<br>" + "<hr>";
      }

      inf.innerHTML += info;
    }
  })();
}

my_information()
```

Once the conditions are met, three alerts on the screen (after clicking the OK button on each alert) should be displayed to the user.

Comment: Quick question: You have ` == ""` in all `if`s except first. Any specific reason?

Comment: The first `if` containing the `for-loop` seems useless to me since you recheck all of it seperatly in the `else if`.

Comment: @Rajesh 
No, there was no particular reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use below condition

```
if (!name && !family && !age)
```

`''` and `null` are falsy values.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Answer (score 0):

This will help you and made you code more simple.

```
if (!name && !family && !age) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < information_statuss.length; i++) {
        alert(information_statuss[i]);
    }
} else if (!name) {
    status = information_statuss[0];
    alert(information_statuss[0]);
} else if (!family) {
    status = information_statuss[1];
    alert(information_statuss[1]);
} else if (!age) {
    status = information_statuss[2];
    alert(information_statuss[2]);
} else {
    status = null;
    var person = new object_constructor(name, family, age);
    console.log(person);
    var people = [];
    people.push(person);
    var inf = document.getElementById('information');
    var info;
    for (I in people) {
        info +=
            "NAME : " + people[I].name + "<br>" +
            "FAMILY : " + people[I].family + "<br>" +
            "AGE : " + people[I].age + "<br>" + "<hr>";
    }

    inf.innerHTML += info;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are checking `name == null` but when user did not fill any name then name parameter goes to blank string not null and the same for family and age.  So use this condition

```
if (name != "" && family != "" && age != "")
```